# Error in Performing Forward Selection in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to perform forward selection for my data frame which I encountered some issues which I think there may be alternatives for it.

I will first show you my code on it:

```
#library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(leaps)
library(MASS)

XBC <- read.csv("path/to/my/file/file.csv")

XBC <- XBC[ -c(1:3) ]
full.model <- lm(Treatment~., data = XBC)
# Stepwise regression model
step.model <- step(full.model, direction = "forward", scope = formula(full.model))
```

This is the error I kept receiving:

```
full.model <- lm(Treatment~., data = XBC)
```

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

As I know the reason why this error occurs was because the data in the column *Treatment* are characters which are the different treatment groups that I have.

Is there any alternative for me to do a forward selection for this *Treatment* group that I have as they are characters.

[Link to dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pou0GSefucOlUb3AwIDXoFmJhNTD11gr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible by providing the data you are using? Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, i have added the link to the dataframe i am using

Comment: Are you sure you want a linear regression model for your data? `lm` needs the y to be numeric. You can see it from `?lm` in R.

Comment: yeah i need it. is there any alternatives other than lm?

Comment: or could i solve it my differentiating my Treatment groups into numbers?

Comment: That depends on your objective